# Trying to test&compile project in Lightdash. Having this error : Could not connect to Lightdash server

Tags: devops, dbt, bi-tool

I am new in Lightdash, and trying to start new project. I ve already created dbt project and pushed it in github. After filling necessary fields in postgres connection and dbt connection I cant test&compile project. See attached screenshot of the problem. It says that: Error running postgres query: Error: self-signed certificate

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHbo2.png)

Comment: Where is the postgres database hosted? This error usually happens because Lightdash is trying to connect to a postgres that enforces SSL but it doesn't have the correct certificates.

Comment: you should check your SSL cert, for simple installation, you can use certbot